# How to get order and sum between three tables on mysql?

Tags: mysql, sum, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort table 1 using the sort on table 2 
and sum the value for each "order number" on table 1 and group by "order number"
and after that bring the client name from table 3 then the result should be like that:

```
sort    ordernumber  sumvalue   name        location    
01          5555        120         Client 2    location 2
01          5498        50          Client 2    location 2
02          2324        50          Client 1    location1
02          4356        30          Client 1    location1
```

tables:

```
table 1 orders
===============
id      ordernumber code_client value
1           2324        01       20 
1           2324        01       30 
1           4356        01       30 
1           5555        02       40 
1           5555        02       40 
1           5498        02       50 
1           5555        02       40 

table 2 sort
============
sort    code_client
1           02
2           01

table 3 client
===============
code_client     name     location
01              Client 1  location1
02              Client 2  location2
```

what i done in the following code is not respect the order even the sum for each ordernumber

```
SELECT orders.ordernumber, 
SUM(orders.value) AS totalordersvalue, 
orders.code_client,
sort.code_client,sort.sort,
client.code_client,client.name, client.location,
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN client 
ON client.code_client = orders.code_client 
LEFT JOIN sort 
ON sort.code_client = orders.code_client 

WHERE orders.id = 1 
GROUP BY orders.ordernumber 
ORDER BY sort.sort
```

there is any way to get the correct order and correct sum for each order as the final result ? thanks

Comment: If `code_client` and `location` in `orders` table are functionally dependent on `ordernumber`, then this table is not normalized. If they are not, then you can not GROUP BY like that. Also you should post your current result.

Comment: Paul you are really right .. i checked right now my original table and there is no location in orders, but only on client table. let me edit the table. thank you

Comment: You still didn't post your current result. Your query should return the "expected" result. Your problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select sort, ordernumber ,totalordersvalue as sumvalue,name,location from 
(
SELECT orders.ordernumber, SUM(orders.value) AS totalordersvalue, 
orders.code_client
FROM orders WHERE orders.id = 1 group by orders.ordernumber,orders.code_client
)A inner join client ON client.code_client = A.code_client
inner join sort ON sort.code_client = A.code_client 
ORDER BY sort.sort
```

Comment: this code do not respect to group by ordernumber .. its repeated on table

Comment: @Mina, have you executed this query? It would definitely show your desired result

Comment: dear i checked now the original tables and in fact there is no location on order table and yes in client .. kindly accept my apologize on that point

Comment: @Mina, ok. So is this answer give u desired result?

Comment: @fa06 Can you explain, why this query should return something different than the original one?

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence of getting a result doesn't matter for you then you can use the following query

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT o.ordernumber,
  s.sort,
  (SELECT sum(os.value) AS sum_value FROM orders AS os WHERE o.ordernumber = 
os.ordernumber GROUP BY os.ordernumber) AS sum_value,
  c.name,
  c.location
FROM
  sort AS s,
  orders AS o,
  client AS c
  WHERE c.code_client = o.code_client AND o.code_client=s.code_client
ORDER BY s.sort;
```

Output:

```
ordernumber  sort    sumvalue   name        location    
5555         01      120        Client 2    location 2
5498         01      50         Client 2    location 2
2324         02      50         Client 1    location1
4356         02      30         Client 1    location1
```

Comment: Ohhh... I wanted same result and this is working in it. Thank you.